# how to map through data grouped with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I've got an array of 35+ store locations that I'm returning from my database. The raw data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 12,
    dealer_code: "TOR",
    name: "Grinyer Doors & Closets",
    company_picture: "company_blank.png",
    URL: "http://toronto.onedaydoorsandclosets.com",
    address: "2225 Dundas Street East",
    city: "Mississauga",
    state: "ON",
    zip: "L4X 1M3",
    phone: "6473601783",
    hrs_mf: "T/W 10:00 am - 6:00 pm, Th 11:00",
    hrs_sat: "F/Sat 10:00 am to 4:00 pm",
    hrs_sun: "Sun/Mon By Appointment",
    owner: "Andy J. Grinyer and Ashley Grinyer",
    sales_email: "ashleygrinyer@gmail.com",
    dealer_emails: "odd2phones@gmail.com",
    google_email: "inquiry@onedaytoronto.com",
    google_cal_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=WEEK&height=600&wkst=2&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=inquiry%40onedaytoronto.com&color=%230F4B38&src=onedaytoronto.com_27u9oep2iovpdkmpp5r1giojjo%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23182C57&src=onedaytoronto.com_7no5uhj4j229c4jn3gd18dhj94%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%2342104A&src=onedaytoronto.com_p940ipdjjoftvavvh13gfot9tk%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23853104&src=onedaytoronto.com_61h07lvglj5g7bmqj8aqt2r12k%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232952A3&src=onedaytoronto.com_bno1ftb9nd9dskrfb6jnoft6d8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%235F6B02&src=onedaytoronto.com_qjp37fdvq5v1n537qa283knsh0%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23875509&ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
    angies_list: "",
    facebook: "",
    google_plus: "",
    houzz: "",
    yelp: "",
    callrail_id: "-1",
    callrail_company_id: "-1",
    contractor_num: "",
    subdomain: "toronto",
    geo_area: "Toronto Ontario",
    page_title: "Grinyer Doors & Closets",
    meta_description:
      "Grinyer Doors & Closets in Mississauga, Toronto Ontairo offers beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors and Closet Organizers, installed in your home with no mess, in just One Day",
    meta_keywords:
      "Grinyer Doors & Closets, Toronto ON area, Beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors, Closet Organizers, installed in one day",
    meta_geo_position: "43.62728980000001; -79.5649536",
    meta_geo_placename: "Toronto ON",
    meta_geo_region: "ON-CA",
    maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d92414.58558064821!2d-79.61798002218458!3d43.62827889693909!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x882b38034f543fcf%3A0x75bdba79ac2ed006!2s2225+Dundas+St+E%2C+Mississauga%2C+ON+L4X+1M3%2C+Canada!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1510088324431" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    sm_maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d92414.58558064821!2d-79.61798002218458!3d43.62827889693909!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x882b38034f543fcf%3A0x75bdba79ac2ed006!2s2225+Dundas+St+E%2C+Mississauga%2C+ON+L4X+1M3%2C+Canada!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1510088324431" width="280" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    corp_ga:
      "<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\r\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-75410322-17\"></script>\r\n<script>\r\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\r\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\r\n  gtag('js', new Date());\r\n\r\n  gtag('config', 'UA-75410322-17');\r\n</script>",
    dealer_ga:
      "<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\r\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-112934473-1\"></script>\r\n<script>\r\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\r\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\r\n  gtag('js', new Date());\r\n\r\n  gtag('config', 'UA-112934473-1');\r\n</script>",
    min_level_see_sales: 3,
    active: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dealer_code: "MFR",
    name: "Modern Doors & Closets",
    company_picture: "company_blank.png",
    URL: "",
    address: "1904 UNITED WAY, SUITE 100\r\nMedford, OR 97504",
    city: "MEDFORD",
    state: "OR",
    zip: "97504",
    phone: "541-843-3007",
    hrs_mf: "",
    hrs_sat: "",
    hrs_sun: "",
    owner: "Ronnie Gobel",
    sales_email: "ronnie@moderndoorsandclosets.com",
    dealer_emails: "odd2phones@gmail.com",
    google_email: "",
    google_cal_embed: "",
    angies_list: "",
    facebook: "",
    google_plus: "",
    houzz: "",
    yelp: "",
    callrail_id: "-1",
    callrail_company_id: "-1",
    contractor_num: "225480",
    subdomain: "oregon",
    geo_area: "",
    page_title: "",
    meta_description: "",
    meta_keywords: "",
    meta_geo_position: "",
    meta_geo_placename: "",
    meta_geo_region: "",
    maps_embed: "",
    sm_maps_embed: "",
    corp_ga: "",
    dealer_ga: "",
    min_level_see_sales: 3,
    active: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 43,
    dealer_code: "PIT",
    name: "Pittsburgh Doors & Closets",
    company_picture: "company_blank.png",
    URL: "pittsburgh.onedaydoorsandclosets.com",
    address: "11269 Perry Highway",
    city: "Wexford",
    state: "PA",
    zip: "15090",
    phone: "724-200-7709",
    hrs_mf: "9:00-5:00 ",
    hrs_sat: "9:00-1:00 ",
    hrs_sun: "By appointment",
    owner: "Scott Satkoske",
    sales_email: "sales@pittdac.com",
    dealer_emails: "odd2phones@gmail.com",
    google_email: "sales@pittdac.com",
    google_cal_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/1/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=sales%40pittdac.com&amp;color=%231B887A&amp;src=pittdac.com_ci0lflb7cmcsjt95k24n5e671o%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%238C500B&amp;src=en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23865A5A&amp;src=pittdac.com_bvdo8ueq7m77v5ppbmgk6frgc0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%235F6B02&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
    angies_list: "",
    facebook:
      "https://business.facebook.com/pg/PittsburghDoorsAndClosets/reviews",
    google_plus: "https://business.google.com/site/l/05941407921024537876",
    houzz: "https://www.houzz.com/pro/pittsburgh-doors-and-closets",
    yelp:
      "https://www.yelp.com/biz/pittsburgh-doors-and-closets-wexford?osq=pittsburgh+doors+and+closets",
    callrail_id: "-1",
    callrail_company_id: "-1",
    contractor_num: "PA140165",
    subdomain: "pittsburgh",
    geo_area: "PITTSBURGH, PA",
    page_title: "Pittsburgh Doors & Closets",
    meta_description:
      "Pittsburgh Doors & Closets in Pittsburgh, offers beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors and Closet Organizers, installed in your home with no mess, in just One Day",
    meta_keywords:
      "Pittsburgh Doors & Closets, Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania area, Beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors, Closet Organizers, installed in one day",
    meta_geo_position: "40.6275; 80.0614",
    meta_geo_placename: "PITTSBURGH, PA",
    meta_geo_region: "PA-US",
    maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d8565.491436036575!2d-80.05813514061147!3d40.6219743315419!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8834899d3f9df1c1%3A0x53a2004389724ee7!2s11269+Perry+Hwy%2C+Wexford%2C+PA+15090!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1527191360692" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    sm_maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d8565.491436036575!2d-80.05813514061147!3d40.6219743315419!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8834899d3f9df1c1%3A0x53a2004389724ee7!2s11269+Perry+Hwy%2C+Wexford%2C+PA+15090!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1527191360692" width="280" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    corp_ga:
      "<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-75410322-1', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');</script>",
    dealer_ga: "",
    min_level_see_sales: 3,
    active: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 56,
    dealer_code: "PHI",
    name: "Philadelphia Doors & Closets",
    company_picture: "company_blank.png",
    URL: "",
    address: "1841 Norristown Rd.",
    city: "Maple Glen",
    state: "PA",
    zip: "19002",
    phone: "",
    hrs_mf: "",
    hrs_sat: "",
    hrs_sun: "",
    owner: "",
    sales_email: "",
    dealer_emails: "odd2phones@gmail.com",
    google_email: "",
    google_cal_embed: "",
    angies_list: "",
    facebook: "",
    google_plus: "",
    houzz: "",
    yelp: "",
    callrail_id: "-1",
    callrail_company_id: "555380281",
    contractor_num: "",
    subdomain: "philadelphia",
    geo_area: "",
    page_title: "",
    meta_description: "",
    meta_keywords: "",
    meta_geo_position: "",
    meta_geo_placename: "",
    meta_geo_region: "",
    maps_embed: "",
    sm_maps_embed: "",
    corp_ga: "",
    dealer_ga: "",
    min_level_see_sales: 3,
    active: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    dealer_code: "SC",
    name: "Southern Doors & Closets",
    company_picture: "company_blank.png",
    URL: "carolina.onedaydoorsandclosets.com",
    address: "1200 Woodruff Rd Building D-1, Suite 100.",
    city: "Greenville",
    state: "SC",
    zip: "29607",
    phone: " 864-373-0079",
    hrs_mf: "9:00 am - 5:30 pm",
    hrs_sat: "10:00 am - 4:00 pm",
    hrs_sun: "Available By Appointment",
    owner: "Chris Arnold",
    sales_email: "chris@carolinadoorsandclosets.com",
    dealer_emails: "odd2phones@gmail.com",
    google_email: "inquiry@onedaycarolina.com",
    google_cal_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=WEEK&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=inquiry%40onedaycarolina.com&amp;color=%231B887A&amp;src=onedaycarolina.com_c6otg7sj1aegitp76n2hdv7m64%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1440E&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
    angies_list: "",
    facebook: "",
    google_plus: "",
    houzz: "",
    yelp: "",
    callrail_id: "-1",
    callrail_company_id: "-1",
    contractor_num: "",
    subdomain: "carolina",
    geo_area: "Greenville, SC",
    page_title: "Southern Doors & Closets",
    meta_description:
      "Southern Doors & Closets in Greenville offers beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors and Closet Organizers, installed in your home with no mess, in just One Day",
    meta_keywords:
      "Southern Doors & Closets, Greenville, SC area, Beautiful Interior Doors, Closet Doors, Closet Organizers, installed in one day",
    meta_geo_position: "34.8482, 82.4035",
    meta_geo_placename: "GREENVILLE, SC",
    meta_geo_region: "SC-US",
    maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d837665.074979648!2d-82.4818390673778!3d34.9032070854684!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88578f6662fa1105%3A0xd8aa9d77bf257696!2sGreenville%2C+SC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1484943807017" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    sm_maps_embed:
      '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d837665.074979648!2d-82.4818390673778!3d34.9032070854684!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88578f6662fa1105%3A0xd8aa9d77bf257696!2sGreenville%2C+SC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1484943807017" width="280" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    corp_ga:
      '<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\n<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-75410322-29"></script>\n<script>\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n  gtag(\'js\', new Date());\n\n  gtag(\'config\', \'UA-75410322-29\');\n</script>\n\n<script type="text/javascript">\n(function(a,e,c,f,g,h,b,d){var k={ak:"862265871",cl:"hqtGCJ_v2nsQj8SUmwM",autoreplace:"864-373-0079"};a[c]=a[c]||function(){(a[c].q=a[c].q||[]).push(arguments)};a[g]||(a[g]=k.ak);b=e.createElement(h);b.async=1;b.src="//www.gstatic.com/wcm/loader.js";d=e.getElementsByTagName(h)[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d);a[f]=function(b,d,e){a[c](2,b,k,d,null,new Date,e)};a[f]()})(window,document,"_googWcmImpl","_googWcmGet","_googWcmAk","script");\n</script>',
    dealer_ga:
      "<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-112925788-1\"></script>\n<script>\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n  gtag('js', new Date());\n\n  gtag('config', 'UA-112925788-1');\n</script>\n",
    min_level_see_sales: 3,
    active: 1,
  },
];
```

Essentially, I want to sort through this data, and display the locations grouped by state; something like this on the Warby Parker site:

[image]

This means taking this data, grouping it by state, and then mapping through it to display. I've used `lodash` and the `groupBy` function, and the data is now returning like this:

```
{
  "CA": [
      {
          "id": 5,
          "dealer_code": "SDC",
          "name": "x Interior Door and Closet Company SD",
          "company_picture": "company_blank.png",
          "URL": "http://sandiegodoorsandclosets.com",
          "address": "123 Doors and Closets Avenue",
          "city": "San Diego",
          "state": "CA",
          "zip": "90122",
          "phone": "858-200-7173",
          "hrs_mf": "",
          "hrs_sat": "",
          "hrs_sun": "",
          "owner": "Glenn Johnson",
          "sales_email": "info@onedayhq.com",
          "dealer_emails": "odd2phones@gmail.com",
          "google_email": "schedule@cdchq.com",
          "google_cal_embed": "<iframe src=\"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=WEEK&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=schedule%40cdchq.com&amp;color=%2323164E&amp;src=cdchq.com_03g5gffu5a5gmt5smmcog9f7og%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23cc209b&amp;src=cdchq.com_hkam4mcg9b67asscst5l082aec%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23865A5A&amp;src=cdchq.com_91l1rake0pl01ssanh7grm1dk8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;src=%23contacts%40group.v.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23865A5A&amp;src=cdchq.com_st6baqemh6l2r43j8unk17pn6g%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%2350ecf8&amp;src=cdchq.com_h9pj9i2o3u41a7soqn25ttoibs%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23853104&amp;src=cdchq.com_f0nsbsmsfv0vqkvddj690bcn78%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%234a7ee7&amp;src=cdchq.com_981ilh7en0tj26og8qtoqsh3ok%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23125A12&amp;src=cdchq.com_cmpi7nd7bgf994jq0mfdo97s9c%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23711616&amp;src=cdchq.com_hpne4fpsse0oneo56btn51tcd8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%2323b1a7&amp;src=cdchq.com_gfh5o59cot5aglarhdme3a1mpc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%2323164E&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles\" style=\"border-width:0\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>",
          "angies_list": "",
          "facebook": "",
          "google_plus": "",
          "houzz": "",
          "yelp": "",
          "callrail_id": "-1",
          "callrail_company_id": "-1",
          "contractor_num": "",
          "subdomain": "sandiego",
          "geo_area": "San Diego",
          "page_title": "",
          "meta_description": "",
          "meta_keywords": "",
          "meta_geo_position": "",
          "meta_geo_placename": "",
          "meta_geo_region": "",
          "maps_embed": "",
          "sm_maps_embed": "",
          "corp_ga": "",
          "dealer_ga": "",
          "min_level_see_sales": 3,
          "active": 1
      },
  ],
  "CO": [
      {
          "id": 11,
          "dealer_code": "DEN",
          "name": "Denver Doors & Closets",
          "company_picture": "company_blank.png",
          "URL": "http://colorado.onedaydoorsandclosets.com",
          "address": "7300 S Alton Way, Unit F",
          "city": "Centennial",
          "state": "CO",
          "zip": "80112",
          "phone": "303-816-3447",
          "hrs_mf": "8:00 am to 6:00 pm",
          "hrs_sat": "10:00 am to 4:00 pm",
          "hrs_sun": "Closed",
          "owner": "Will Bigler and Kathleen Bigler",
          "sales_email": "will@denverdoorsandclosets.com",
          "dealer_emails": "odd2phones@gmail.com",
          "google_email": "inquiry@onedaycolorado.com",
          "google_cal_embed": "<iframe src=\"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=WEEK&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=inquiry%40onedaycolorado.com&amp;color=%231B887A&amp;src=onedaycolorado.com_4ckkptt4l73hgqp82dfftpjmj8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;src=onedaycolorado.com_1f2jdj02lhf1qd0h7ah4e7f5mg%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%238D6F47&amp;ctz=America%2FDenver\" style=\"border-width:0\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>",
          "angies_list": "",
          "facebook": "",
          "google_plus": "",
          "houzz": "",
          "yelp": "",
          "callrail_id": "-1",
          "callrail_company_id": "278512782",
          "contractor_num": "",
          "subdomain": "colorado",
          "geo_area": "Denver",
          "page_title": "Denver Doors & Closets",
          "meta_description": "Denver Doors & Closets in Denver Sales Event offers installed interior doors from $159 each, $100 off closet door sets and free installation for closet organizers in Denver, CO 80012",
          "meta_keywords": "Denver Doors & Closets Denver,Installed interior doors from $159, FREE installation for Closet Organizers, Denver, CO 80012",
          "meta_geo_position": "LAT 39.6993 ; LONG -104.8375 ",
          "meta_geo_placename": "DENVER",
          "meta_geo_region": "CO-US",
          "maps_embed": "<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d196281.12937287416!2d-104.9951946882819!3d39.76451867255984!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x876b80aa231f17cf%3A0x118ef4f8278a36d6!2sDenver%2C+CO!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1471565161359\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
          "sm_maps_embed": "<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d196281.12937287416!2d-104.9951946882819!3d39.76451867255984!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x876b80aa231f17cf%3A0x118ef4f8278a36d6!2sDenver%2C+CO!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1471565161359\" width=\"280\" height=\"200\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
          "corp_ga": "<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-75410322-15\"></script>\n<script>\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n  gtag('js', new Date());\n\n  gtag('config', 'UA-75410322-15');\n</script>\n",
          "dealer_ga": "<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-112907322-1\"></script>\n<script>\n  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n  gtag('js', new Date());\n\n  gtag('config', 'UA-112907322-1');\n</script>\n",
          "min_level_see_sales": 6,
          "active": 1
      }
  ]
}
```

So, I've got the raw data grouped into new objects by state. However, I'm still struggling to actually map through this data and display it how I need. I tried mutating this data again with

```
const groups = _.groupBy(locations, 'state');
const locationsByState = Object.entries(groups);
```

and then mapping through `locationsByState`, but I'm still not getting what I need, similar to the screenshot posted above. What can I do to iterate through this data?

Thanks.

Comment: `locationsByState` is an array of arrays. Check the documentation of `Object.entries()` for the structure. tl:dr; `locationsByState[0]` would be (for your grouped example): `[ "CA", [ ... ] ]`. You want the second element of that "inner" array. Combine some loops or `.forEach()`s or `.map()`s or ...

Comment: Step#1: Map over raw data to extract only those fields you need.
Step#2: Group this mapped data by `state` to get state-wise info.

You have already done this part.
Step#3: ForEach key of grouped data, you get an array of values. Keys are your states, while values against them are stores. So you should somehow map these stores info to appropriate html.

Step#4: Once you have it, run over it and generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it done:

Like above, I grouped my data by `state` using lodash:

```
const groups = _.groupBy(data, 'state');
const locationsByState = Object.entries(groups);
```

I then map through the `locationsByState` array, and create a `const` for the first index in `group`, which is an array of all locations as sorted by lodash, and then map through that array to return the groups of locations as needed.

```
{
  locationsByState
    ? locationsByState.map((group, index) => {
        const stateName = group[0];
        const locationByState = group[1];

        return (
          <div className={s.allLocations__region} key={index}>
            <Heading tag="h3" className={s.stateName}>
              {convertRegion(stateName)}
            </Heading>
            <div className={s.allLocations__group}>
              {locationByState.map((dealer, i) => {
                return (
                  <LocationCard
                    key={i}
                    dealer={dealer}
                    className={s.allLocations__location}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    : null;
}
```

I have various other components and utilities that I'm utilizing here, but I pass the `dealer` object to my `LocationCard` component, and display the data there. This works perfectly for what I need.